# Bonding different ISPs in a gateway in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, network-bonding

I am using four ISPs connections in a gateway and would like 
to use them in mode 0 (round robin).

All of ISPs are having static IPs.
I have been trying to bond ISPs, but unable to suceed.
I have tried both netplan and interfaces mode to configure
in round robin mode but failed.

I have used the following code to connect atleast two ISPs

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

auto enp4s5f0
    iface enp4s5f0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto enp4s5f1
    iface enp4s5f1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0  

auto bond0
    iface bond0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.201
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    bond-mode round-robin
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-slaves none
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have four different ISP connections, with different IPs on each connection? In that case you can't bond them. You'll have to do round robin load balancing at the routing level afaik.

Comment: @vidarlo Yes I have different IPs for each connection.

Comment: Then you can't use bonding. EOD. You'll have to do your scheduling at L3, not L2.